# Granting KMS does not allow allow to encrypt

Tags: amazon-kms

I am trying to push notifications to a SNS topic encrypted with a KMS key. The push is sent by role R1.
Role R1 has following permissions:

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "sns:Publish",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:..sns..:topicA",
            "arn:..sns..:topicB",
        ],
        "Sid": ""
    },
    {
        "Action": "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:kms:...:key/keyTopicA",
            "arn:aws:kms:...:key/keyTopicB"
        ],
        "Sid": ""
    }
],
"Version": "2012-10-17"
```

}

My key A and B have the following Key Policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Enable IAM policies",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>:root"
        },
        "Action": "kms:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

So no KeyPolicy allow my role explicitly, the permission is done through the following grants:

```
{
   "Grants":[
      {
         "KeyId":"arn:aws:kms:...:key/keyTopicA",
         "GrantId":"<GrantID>",
         "Name":"grantA",
         "GranteePrincipal":"arn:aws:iam::...:role/R1",
         "IssuingAccount":"arn:aws:iam::...:root",
         "Operations":[
            "GenerateDataKey"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Same thing for KeyTopicB

Now, when I try to push notification, I get the following error:

> The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access. (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;

I thought it might be one of the other possibility (wrong key/region), but if I modify the Key policy to explicitly add my role R1, then all is good this work. I am very confused why doing it with a Grant does not work. Am I missing something on how Grant works?